# Python difference between method and lambda

Tags: python, lambda

What are the possible niuances (differences) between a method and a lambda? I have an identity function and wonder does it make much of a difference how I define it?

```
def ident(x): return x
ident = lambda x: x
```

These are surely functionally the same, but do they differ in performance or otherwise?

Comment: Neither of those is a method.

Comment: You mean its a function? That is just words picking, honestly.

Comment: Using precise vocabulary is important to understand the inner workings; don't dismiss it.

Comment: No, it's *isn't just word picking*. That is a *crucial, functional difference in Python*. Note, you've tagged this with staticmethod, but that is just plain wrong.

Comment: But, to get to your question, performance differences are negligible, but more importantly, `lambda` functions only support expressions, where's `def` statements can have any combination of complex statements in their body. The *only* purpose of lambda is for convenience, usually as an argument to a higher order function, and if you assign lambda functions to a name, that negates their only use case. Indeed, although it is allowed, it is explicitly recommended against by PEP8 style guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Both do the same, but neither is a method; the first is a function, the second, an anonymous function that you named by assigning it to a variable.

#### from the comments:

> performance differences are negligible, but more importantly, lambda
> functions only support expressions, where's def statements can have
> any combination of complex statements in their body. The only purpose
> of lambda is for convenience, usually as an argument to a higher order
> function, and if you assign lambda functions to a name, that negates
> their only use case. Indeed, although it is allowed, it is explicitly
> recommended against by PEP8 style guidelines.
> ~ juanpa.arrivillaga